# How did Shaw know that Marco was instructed to kill the President-Elect?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-manchurian-candidate

In the movie "The Manchurian Candidate" from 2004 Ben Marco was instructed by Eleanor Prentiss Shaw (Meryl Streep) to kill the president-elect. But how did Raymond Shaw know and thus interfere?